# How can I plot this integral?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am in the following situation: I have a complicated ODE for the function `f[x]` that has no anlytical solution and an integral that depends on `f[x]`: how can I plot the integral?

As a MWE consider the following situation:

```
f'[x] = Sqrt[f[x]]
Integrate[f[x]^2,x]
```

**EDIT** This is what I get with the following attempt:

```
NDSolve[{f'[x] == Sqrt[f[x]], f[0] == 1}, f, {x, 0, 10}]
Plot[Integrate[f[x]^2, x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: can you not solve the ODE numerically and obtain `f(x)` that way? Then you can integrate it.

Comment: I can solve the ODE  numerically, but I don't know how to use the result to plot the integral.

Comment: result of `NDSolve` is a function. Which is `f[x]`. Then plug it into the integrand there and integrate it. You'll get a result which you can plot.

Comment: @Nasser see my edit

Comment: Do you want to integrate `f[x]` or `f[x]^2` (cf. your MWE)?

Comment: @gwr I just noted that I needed to integrate `f[x]^2` I will correct the post

Comment: This is to calculate both results:`DSolve[f'[x] == Sqrt[f[x]] && f [0] == 1, f, x]` `Integrate[f[x]^2 /. %, x]` `Plot[
 %,
 {x, 0, 10}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
sol = First@NDSolve[{f'[x] == Sqrt[f[x]], f[0] == 1}, f, {x, 0, 10}];
Plot[Evaluate[Integrate[f[x] /. sol, x]], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yes it does! thank you

Comment: ˋDSolveˋ will find 2 solutions in this case (cf. comments above) - how can this be achieved with ˋNDSolveˋ? (+1 of course)

Answer (score 1):

You might also simply introduce another differential equation to obtain the antiderivative for `f[x]`:

```
sol = First @ NDSolve[
    {
       f'[x] == Sqrt @ f[x],
       g'[x] == f[x]^2, (* so g[x] is the antiderivative of f[x]^2 *)
        f[0] == 1,
        g[0] == 0
    }
    , { f, g }
    , { x, 0, 10 }
];
Plot[ g[x] /. sol, { x, 0, 10 } ]
```

[image: Plot of the antiderivative]